# Scope of Groovy's ExpandoMetaClass?

Tags: java, groovy, metaprogramming, expandometaclass

Groovy exposes an [`ExpandoMetaClass`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/ExpandoMetaClass) that allows you to dynamically add instance and class methods/properties to a POJO. I would like to use it to add an instance method to one of my Java classes:

```
public class Fizz {
    // ...etc.
}

Fizz fizz = new Fizz();
fizz.metaClass.doStuff = { String blah -> fizz.buzz(blah) }
```

This would be the equivalent to refactoring the `Fizz` class to have:

```
public class Fizz {
    // ctors, getters/setters, etc...

    public void doStuff(String blah) {
        buzz(blah);
    }
}
```

My question:

**Does this add `doStuff(String blah)` to only this particular instance of `Fizz`? Or do all instances of `Fizz` now have a `doStuff(String blah)` instance method?**

If the former, how do I get all instances of `Fizz` to have the `doStuff` instance method? I know that if I made the Groovy:

```
fizz.metaClass.doStuff << { String blah -> fizz.buzz(blah) }
```

Then that would add a static class method to `Fizz`, such as `Fizz.doStuff(String blah)`, but that's not what I want. I just want all instances of `Fizz` to now have an instance method called `doStuff`. Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, when you add to the main class of Fizz, its instances do not get the method as the instances have already been factored out and added to memory.

So one way of approaching this is to use the method signature from the original class. Therefore instead of

`fizz.doStuff(blah)`

call the method of the class. Therefore

`fizz.&doStuff(blah)`

This gets the method signature from the originating class, but uses the attributes from the instance. However as you can imagine, since its calling the originating class, this is a slightly heavy call.

Now one alternative of pushing out to every instance is to make the instances ExpandoMetaClass instances of Fizz. Hence...

```
Fizz.metaClass.doStuff = {return "blah"}
fizz = new Fizz()
Fizz.metaClass.doOtherStuff = {return "more blah"}
assert fizz.doOtherStuff() == "more blah"
```

Hope this helps

**UPDATE:**

Full code example:

```
class Fizz{
}

Fizz.metaClass.doOtherStuff = {return "more blah"}
def fizz = new Fizz()
assert fizz.doOtherStuff() == "more blah"

def fizz1 = new Fizz()
assert fizz1.doOtherStuff() == "more blah"
```

Comment: Thanks @mugdho (+1) - but you sort of threw me off guard with the whole "&doStuff()" stuff... can you provide a full code example demonstrating how to use ExpandoMetaclass to attach `doStuff` as an instance method to all instances of `Fizz`? Thanks again!

Comment: +1. In order to add static methods to metaClass use `Fizz.metaClass.'static'.fooStuff = {.....}`

Comment: @TicketMonster Mark the difference, he is adding method to the metaClass of `Fizz` class instead of `fizz` instance. That makes it possible to have `doStuff` available for all instances of Fizz.

Comment: Thanks @dmahapatro (+1) - but still not seeing the "forest" through the "trees". A full code example would really pull it all together for me...

Comment: So basically we need to update an object calling the metaClass method to convert its adaptee into from a regular MetaClassImpl to an ExpandoMetaClass. An adaptee is the the attribute that decides what runs the implementation (If that makes sense :-))

Comment: @TicketMonster There you go. See the update to mugdho's answer.

Comment: Just what I was about to add as well :). Thanks dmahapatro!

Comment: Thanks @mugdho (+1) - that makes perfect sense! Last followup question: can I assume that if I wanted `doOtherStuff` to accept an integer parameter, that I could write it like so: `Fizz.metaClass.doOtherStuff = { int x -> return "more blah"}`? Then I could invoke it like so: `fizz.doOtherStuff(7);`? Am I correct? Thanks again!